# Source for ArcGIS Layout Templates?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, layouts

I am running v10 of ArcGIS for Desktop.
I am aware of the OTB templates provided with ArcGIS.
- However, I would like to supplement these layouts with additional layouts.

[image]

I am also aware of the [Map Template Gallery](http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/map-templates), but this seems to be more around data models and I am after the actual **print layout templates.**

In particular I am looking for [Local Government style templates](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=1fd4b1022f1446499721d7a91e94c664), but the only downloads I can find seem to be again around the data model side of things as opposed to the actual print templates.

Has anyone seen (perhaps on ArcScripts) a bundle of templates that I can add to ArcGIS Desktop so that I can switch to them in my Layout View?

Comment: If you don't find anything suitable to download it is very easy to create and organise your own map templates at ArcGIS 10: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s90000002w000000.htm

Comment: and you may be able to help jumpstart the commmunity by "uploading" any templates you end up with to the arcgis.com gallery.

Comment: @Brad - Perhaps if there is no 'one resource' answer, then we could post this again in Meta, and using something like a public dropbox, everyone could upload their templates, and then we upload it to ArcGIS.com, from GIS-SE?